# Raspberry Pi 4 - Dual Audio with Dual HDMI

Tags: audio, hdmi, pi-4

I have a Raspberry Pi 4. The thing is, I want to play 2 videos at the same time, since the RPi-4 has 2 HDMI outputs. BUT I also want to have split audio. The audio from video 1 should go out over the first HDMI (labeled as HDMI0), the audio of the second video should go out through the second HDMI (labeled HDMI1).

Imagine the following:
I turn on screen 1. I see the first video with its sound.
Then, I turn screen 1 off and turn screen 2 on. I hear and see the video 2, while the other one is being played silently on the turned off monitor. Both videos need to be in 4K resolution.

Is this possible? I could not find any resources regarding this specific set up. Please note, that it is important to achieve this with this exact set up. Everything should run independently, as if it were controlled by 2 RPi's.

Thanks for your time and knowledge.

Best.

Comment: I am unaware of how to do this but you will need to go to display options and move display 2 out of display 1 so they don't mirror content, the default.

Comment: Have a read of https://www.elektormagazine.com/news/review-raspberry-pi-4 It's possible but looks like not yet. And only at 30fps.

Comment: Thanks for the note! I will be sure to do this right in the beginning for further work.

Comment: Hey there, 30fps is fine so far. I am sure I will find a work around. What do you mean by "not yet"? I assume you get the feel, that the technology might provide everything needed, but there is no implementation? Thanks!